# Attempt to present <app.TabController> on <app.ViewController> which is already presenting <UIAlertController> in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uialertcontroller

Ok so I'm adding a `please wait` popup for the operation that takes longer than usual in my ios app.

I have a segue from my ViewController to TabController and when I invoke it like this:

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("openMainApp", sender: self)
```

everything works fine.

But when I surround it with:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Please wait...", preferredStyle: .Alert)

alert.view.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
let loadingIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(10, 5, 50, 50)) as UIActivityIndicatorView
loadingIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
loadingIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray
loadingIndicator.startAnimating();

alert.view.addSubview(loadingIndicator)
presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("openMainApp", sender: self)

dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
```

then I'm getting a warning:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <app.TabController: 0x7ff6dc00bd40>  
on <app.ViewController: 0x7ff6d9cf6600> which is already presenting 
<UIAlertController: 0x7ff6d9d78530>
```

how can I skip this warning?

Answer (score 1):

While the source for this warning is still a mystery to me, there is a way to skip the warning.

1. Delete the segue from storyboard
2. Give storyboard ID to your view controller, something like:

   [image]
3. Replace
   `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("openMainApp", sender: self)` 
   with

   ```
   let viewController: UIViewController =
     self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainScene")
   self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Idan's answer may work, but I would recommend using something like [MBProgressHud](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) or [SVProgressHud](https://github.com/SVProgressHUD/SVProgressHUD). It looks like swift doesn't like it when you perform a segue before dismissing the alert controller because it is it's own view controller. [Here](https://youtu.be/vwkOERJvuL0) is how to implement MBProgressHud. [Here](https://youtu.be/ZpK5KQdn95w) is how to implement SVProgressHud. If you don't want to use CocoaPods, you just download the zip file and add the .m and .h file into your project.